# Shell parameter substitution with sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh, alpine-linux

In bash following command works where it use parameter substitution

```
$ VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; echo ${!PARAM}
20m
```

However in Alpine container with sh the same command fails

```
# VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; echo ${!PARAM}
/bin/sh: syntax error: bad substitution
```

What would be the correct syntax to achieve same outcome using /bin/sh ?

Comment: `${!PARAM}` is a bash extension, Alpine is using `sh`.

Comment: Yes sure so I am seeking a method to get same behaviour in sh?

Comment: The equivalent requires using `eval`

Comment: Using `eval "echo $PARAM"` output the value VALUE_AUS, but what required is 20m which is the value of the VALUE_AUS parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indirect variables is a `bash` extension.

If Alpine can't run `bash`, you'll need to use `eval` to emulate this.

```
# VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; eval "echo \"\$${PARAM}\""
```

Comment: This is the output I get with alpine docker sh. Do you get it working? `# VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; eval "echo \"${!PARAM}\""
/bin/sh: syntax error: bad substitution`

Comment: `docker run -it alpine
/ # VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; eval "echo \"${!PARAM}\""
/bin/sh: syntax error: bad substitution`

Comment: I forgot to remove the `!`

Comment: Still I don't get the desired output. Value needed it 20m but output I get is VALUE_AUS `docker run -it alpine
/ # VALUE_AUS=20m; COUNTRY=AUS; PARAM=VALUE_$COUNTRY; eval "echo \"${PARAM}\""
VALUE_AUS`

Comment: I needed an escaped `$` in it.